# Nagios vuelca los comandos de chequeos en el historial

Tags: línea-de-comandos

Esto ocurrió en una maquina con Debian 9. El mensaje que aparece en el historial es algo como:

> 412  echo UPTIME_CMD_OP_ST;uptime|cut -d ',' -f1,2|tr -s ' ' '^'|cut -d '^' -f 2-;echo UPTIME_CMD_OP_END
>   413  echo CPUUTIL_CMD_OP_ST;/usr/bin/vmstat 1 3;echo CPUUTIL_CMD_OP_END
>   414  echo LINUXZOMBIEPROCESSCOUNT_CMD_OP_ST;/bin/ps -eo fname,pcpu,pmem,command|egrep '%CPU|defunct';echo 
>    LINUXZOMBIEPROCESSCOUNT_CMD_OP_END
>   415  echo LINUXPROCESSCOUNT_CMD_OP_ST;/bin/ps -ef --no-headers | wc -l;echo LINUXPROCESSCOUNT_CMD_OP_END
>   416  echo CPUCORE_CMD_OP_ST;mpstat -P ALL 1 3;echo CPUCORE_CMD_OP_END
>   417  echo DISKUTIL_CMD_OP_ST;/bin/df -Pm |awk '{print $(NF-3)  " " $(NF-2) " " $(NF-1)  " " $NF}';echo DISKUTIL_CMD_OP_END
>   418  echo MEMUTIL_CMD_OP_ST;free -b;echo MEMUTIL_CMD_OP_END
>   419  echo THREADCOUNT_CMD_OP_ST;ps -eo nlwp | awk '{ threadcount += $1 } END { print threadcount }';echo THREADCOUNT_CMD_OP_END
>   420  echo SYSLOAD_CMD_OP_ST;uptime;echo SYSLOAD_CMD_OP_END
>   421  echo UPTIME_CMD_OP_ST;uptime|cut -d ',' -f1,2|tr -s ' ' '^'|cut -d '^' -f 2-;echo UPTIME_CMD_OP_END
>   422  echo CPUUTIL_CMD_OP_ST;/usr/bin/vmstat 1 3;echo CPUUTIL_CMD_OP_END
>   423  echo LINUXZOMBIEPROCESSCOUNT_CMD_OP_ST;/bin/ps -eo fname,pcpu,pmem,command|egrep '%CPU|defunct';echo LINUXZOMBIEPROCESSCOUNT_CMD_OP_END
>   424  echo LINUXPROCESSCOUNT_CMD_OP_ST;/bin/ps -ef --no-headers | wc -l;echo LINUXPROCESSCOUNT_CMD_OP_END
>   425  echo CPUCORE_CMD_OP_ST;mpstat -P ALL 1 3;echo CPUCORE_CMD_OP_END
>   426  echo DISKUTIL_CMD_OP_ST;/bin/df -Pm |awk '{print $(NF-3)  " " $(NF-2) " " $(NF-1)  " " $NF}';echo DISKUTIL_CMD_OP_END
>   427  echo MEMUTIL_CMD_OP_ST;free -b;echo MEMUTIL_CMD_OP_END
>   428  echo THREADCOUNT_CMD_OP_ST;ps -eo nlwp | awk '{ threadcount += $1 } END { print threadcount }';echo THREADCOUNT_CMD_OP_END
>   429  echo SYSLOAD_CMD_OP_ST;uptime;echo SYSLOAD_CMD_OP_END
>   430  echo UPTIME_CMD_OP_ST;uptime|cut -d ',' -f1,2|tr -s ' ' '^'|cut -d '^' -f 2-;echo UPTIME_CMD_OP_END
>   431  echo CPUUTIL_CMD_OP_ST;/usr/bin/vmstat 1 3;echo CPUUTIL_CMD_OP_END
>   432  echo LINUXZOMBIEPROCESSCOUNT_CMD_OP_ST;/bin/ps -eo fname,pcpu,pmem,command|egrep '%CPU|defu
>    .
>    .
>    .

En un principio **NRPE** no estaba instalado, solo xinetd. Instalé **NRPE 3.2.1**, configuré algunos comandos y fui a `/etc/crontab` por si algún proceso se estaba ejecutando de forma periódica. Aparecen mas de 500 mensajes a diario.
Alguien sabe que puede ocurrir?

La configuración nrpe es esta:

```
log_facility=daemon`introducir el código aquí`

# PID FILE
# The name of the file in which the NRPE daemon should write it's process ID
# number.  The file is only written if the NRPE daemon is started by the root
# user and is running in standalone mode.

pid_file=/var/run/nrpe/nrpe.pid

# PORT NUMBER
# Port number we should wait for connections on.
# NOTE: This must be a non-priviledged port (i.e. > 1024).
# NOTE: This option is ignored if NRPE is running under either inetd or xinetd

server_port=5666

# SERVER ADDRESS
# Address that nrpe should bind to in case there are more than one interface
# and you do not want nrpe to bind on all interfaces.
# NOTE: This option is ignored if NRPE is running under either inetd or xinetd

#server_address=127.0.0.1

# NRPE USER
# This determines the effective user that the NRPE daemon should run as.
# You can either supply a username or a UID.
#
# NOTE: This option is ignored if NRPE is running under either inetd or xinetd

nrpe_user=nagios

# NRPE GROUP
# This determines the effective group that the NRPE daemon should run as.
# You can either supply a group name or a GID.
#
# NOTE: This option is ignored if NRPE is running under either inetd or xinetd

nrpe_group=nagios

# ALLOWED HOST ADDRESSES
# This is an optional comma-delimited list of IP address or hostnames
# that are allowed to talk to the NRPE daemon.
#
# Note: The daemon only does rudimentary checking of the client's IP
# address.  I would highly recommend adding entries in your /etc/hosts.allow
# file to allow only the specified host to connect to the port
# you are running this daemon on.
#
# NOTE: This option is ignored if NRPE is running under either inetd or xinetd
allowed_hosts=127.0.0.1,192.168.100.3

# COMMAND ARGUMENT PROCESSING
# This option determines whether or not the NRPE daemon will allow clients
# to specify arguments to commands that are executed.  This option only works
# if the daemon was configured with the --enable-command-args configure script
# option.
#
# *** ENABLING THIS OPTION IS A SECURITY RISK! ***
# Read the SECURITY file for information on some of the security implications
# of enabling this variable.
#
# Values: 0=do not allow arguments, 1=allow command arguments

dont_blame_nrpe=1 

# COMMAND PREFIX
# This option allows you to prefix all commands with a user-defined string.
# A space is automatically added between the specified prefix string and the
# command line from the command definition.
#
# *** THIS EXAMPLE MAY POSE A POTENTIAL SECURITY RISK, SO USE WITH CAUTION! ***
# Usage scenario:
# Execute restricted commmands using sudo.  For this to work, you need to add
# the nagios user to your /etc/sudoers.  An example entry for alllowing
# execution of the plugins from might be:
#
# nagios          ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/lib/nagios/plugins/
#
# This lets the nagios user run all commands in that directory (and only them)
# without asking for a password.  If you do this, make sure you don't give
# random users write access to that directory or its contents!

# command_prefix=/usr/bin/sudo

# DEBUGGING OPTION
# This option determines whether or not debugging messages are logged to the
# syslog facility.
# Values: 0=debugging off, 1=debugging on

debug=0

# COMMAND TIMEOUT
# This specifies the maximum number of seconds that the NRPE daemon will
# allow plugins to finish executing before killing them off.

command_timeout=60

# CONNECTION TIMEOUT
# This specifies the maximum number of seconds that the NRPE daemon will
# wait for a connection to be established before exiting. This is sometimes
# seen where a network problem stops the SSL being established even though
# all network sessions are connected. This causes the nrpe daemons to
# accumulate, eating system resources. Do not set this too low.

connection_timeout=300

# WEEK RANDOM SEED OPTION
# This directive allows you to use SSL even if your system does not have
# a /dev/random or /dev/urandom (on purpose or because the necessary patches
# were not applied). The random number generator will be seeded from a file
# which is either a file pointed to by the environment valiable $RANDFILE
# or $HOME/.rnd. If neither exists, the pseudo random number generator will
# be initialized and a warning will be issued.
# Values: 0=only seed from /dev/[u]random, 1=also seed from weak randomness

#allow_weak_random_seed=1

# INCLUDE CONFIG FILE
# This directive allows you to include definitions from an external config file.
#include=<somefile.cfg>

# INCLUDE CONFIG DIRECTORY
# This directive allows you to include definitions from config files (with a
# .cfg extension) in one or more directories (with recursion).

#include_dir=<somedirectory>
include_dir=/usr/local/nagios/etc/nrpe    

# COMMAND DEFINITIONS
# Command definitions that this daemon will run.  Definitions
# are in the following format:
#
# command[<command_name>]=<command_line>
#
# When the daemon receives a request to return the results of <command_name>
# it will execute the command specified by the <command_line> argument.
#
# Unlike Nagios, the command line cannot contain macros - it must be
# typed exactly as it should be executed.
#
# Note: Any plugins that are used in the command lines must reside
# on the machine that this daemon is running on!  The examples below
# assume that you have plugins installed in a /usr/local/nagios/libexec
# directory.  Also note that you will have to modify the definitions below
# to match the argument format the plugins expect.  Remember, these are
# examples only!

# The following examples use hardcoded command arguments...

#command[check_users]=/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_users -w 5 -c 10
#command[check_load]=/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_load -w 15,10,5 -c 30,25,20
#command[check_hda1]=/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_disk -w 20% -c 10% -p /dev/hda1
#command[check_zombie_procs]=/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_procs -w 5 -c 10 -s Z
#command[check_total_procs]=/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_procs -w 150 -c 200
command[check_cpu_perf]=/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_cpu_perf.sh $ARG1$ $ARG2$

command[check_load]=/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_load -w $ARG1$ -c $ARG2$

#command[check_disk]=/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_disk -f -w $ARG1$ -c $ARG2$ -W $ARG3$ -K $ARG4$ -E $ARG5$
command[check_disk]=/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_disk -w $ARG1$ -c $ARG2$ -W $ARG3$ -K $ARG4$ -p $ARG5$

#command[check_swap]=sudo /usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_swap -w 20% -c 10%
command[check_swap]=/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_swap -w $ARG1$ -c $ARG2$

command[check_proceso]=/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_procs -c "1:" --ereg-argument-array="jboss"

command[check_jbosseap_MemoryHeapUsed]=/usr/bin/sudo /usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_jbosseap_MemoryHeapUsed $ARG1$ $ARG2$ $ARG3$
command[check_jbosseap_ThreadCount]=/usr/bin/sudo /usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_jbosseap_ThreadCount $ARG1$ $ARG2$ $ARG3$
command[check_jbosseap_CLASSLOADED]=/usr/bin/sudo /usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_jbosseap_CLASSLOADED $ARG1$ $ARG2$ $ARG3$

# The following examples allow user-supplied arguments and can
# only be used if the NRPE daemon was compiled with support for
# command arguments *AND* the dont_blame_nrpe directive in this
# config file is set to '1'.  This poses a potential security risk, so
# make sure you read the SECURITY file before doing this.

#command[check_users]=/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_users -w $ARG1$ -c $ARG2$
#command[check_load]=/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_load -w $ARG1$ -c $ARG2$
#command[check_disk]=/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_disk -w $ARG1$ -c $ARG2$ -p $ARG3$
#command[check_procs]=/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_procs -w $ARG1$ -c $ARG2$ -s $ARG3$
```

Y el crontab vacío:

```
# /etc/crontab: system-wide crontab
# Unlike any other crontab you don't have to run the `crontab'
# command to install the new version when you edit this file
# and files in /etc/cron.d. These files also have username fields,
# that none of the other crontabs do.

  SHELL=/bin/sh
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin

# m h dom mon dow user  command
17 *    * * *   root    cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly
25 6    * * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.daily )
47 6    * * 7   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.weekly )
52 6    1 * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.monthly )
```

Comment: Deberías editar la pregunta y traducir el texto (párrafo final) al español puesto que estás en SO en español.

Comment: Creo que, para poder cualquier tipo de ayuda, tu pregunta necesita incluir la configuración de nrpe en el nodo